# Adding line break to text message using Telegram bot

Tags: linux, bash, telegram-bot

im trying to send telegram messages from Linux bash using curl. My current problem is that i am unable to send line breaks in the message.

My code is something like this:

```
msg="<a href=\"${img}\">&#160;</a><b>${title}</b><a href=\"${lnk}\">MORE INFO</a>"

curl --data chat_id=$chatID --data-urlencode "text=${msg}" "https://api.telegram.org/bot${apik}/sendMessage?parse_mode=HTML"
```

i tried with `</br>` `\n` `%0D%0A`, and none work.

Comment: use simple quotes `msg='something'$variable'something'`

Comment: @IporSircer Wouldn't it be better to use simple quotes as HTML attributes delimiters and keep the double quotes around the variable? i.e. `msg="<a href='$img'>"`

Comment: More on topic, [it looks like the API doesn't support linebreak tags](https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#html-style). I see however it supports `<pre>` tags, in which whitespace are to be displayed as-is, so a `\n` in a `<pre>` should lead to a linefeed. I don't know the first thing about telegram so I don't know if it's the right way to handle this, but it could be a solution. It might also lead to other style changes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe try setting your `$msg` variable as a **[`heredoc`](http://www.tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/here-docs.html)**:

```
#!/bin/bash

img="one"
title="two"
lnk="three"

read -r -d '' msg <<EOT
<a href="${img}"></a>
<b>"${title}"</b>
<a href="${lnk}">MORE INFO</a>
EOT

curl --data chat_id="$chatID" --data-urlencode "text=${msg}" "https://api.telegram.org/bot${apik}/sendMessage?parse_mode=HTML"
```

↳ [Wikipedia : Here Documents](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Here_document)